# What value request.getHeader("Host") returns

Tags: java, jsp

The link to my application is https://xxxx.abcd.com

Now when hit this URL in the browser what do I get the value in the string if i give

```
   String host=request.getHeader("Host");
```

Comment: System.out.println(host);//abcd(Host name)

Comment: My application is hosted over a web server, I am unable to run it currently. I have searched this over the internet but haven't got the answer yet.

Comment: @PavelHoral The 'hosts' file has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @EJP it seemed to me that the OP does not know how to test for this on his local machine. Hence advice to use local host to emulate real host access.

Comment: @PavelHoral The OP doesn't know what `String host=request.getHeader("Host")` returns, and fiddling around with `/etc/hosts` doesn't 'emulate real host access'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC 2616-sec14](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)

> The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port number of the resource being requested, as obtained from the original URI given by the user or referring resource.

```
request.getHeader("Host");
```

will return the value of the "Host" (in your case  xxxxx.abcd.com) header in the request.

You can use following program to get the all header information.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RequestHeaderServlet
*/
@WebServlet("/RequestHeaderServlet")
public class RequestHeaderServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public RequestHeaderServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Enumeration en = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(en.hasMoreElements()){

        //get header name Accept,Accept-Charset,Authorization,Connection,Host etc.   
        String headerName = (String) en.nextElement(); //nextElement() returns Object need type cast

        //get the value of the headerName 
        String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);

        //display on browser
        out.print("Header Name = "+ headerName + " " + " Header Value = "+ headerValue + "<br>");

    }
out.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
}
```

#### Related links

- [Servlet Tutorial Request Headers](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html#Section3)
- [tutorialspoint.com header example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-client-request.htm)

Comment: I thought the same thing but he's requesting it via `HTTPS` and I haven't managed to confirm if this will omit the port after the host name so perhaps it will be `xxxx.abcd.com:443`

Comment: Incorrect, along with your source. -1, and there should be another -1 for citing a non-normative reference. The normative reference in this case is the Servlet Specification. @radimpe Port numbers aren't part of host names.

Comment: @EJP according to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) it is.

Comment: I guess you didn't read it but check 14.23: _A "host" without any trailing **port** information implies the default port for the service requested_

Comment: @radimpe Oops, correct, but see my answer. This one is incorrect.

Comment: @Aniket You keep editing this answer without actually fixing it. Why is that? And your example doesn't support your contention, in fact it disproves it comprehensively. Have you read it? Request URI=`"/servlet/hall.ShowRequestHeaders"`, and Host:=`"webdev.apl.jph.edu".`

Comment: @Aniket Why not *fix your answer?* instead of leaving all this misinformation here forever to confuse future readers? Or delete it?

Comment: @Aniket This is still incomplete without the information that `getHeader("Host")` returns the value of this header.

Answer (score 0):

It will return the value of the "Host" header in the request, which must be "as obtained from the original URI given by the user or referring resource". See [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23).

Comment: Sir, I have edited answer, still you feel it is not up to the mark than please, suggest me what is wrong? Thanks for telling me wrong.

Comment: What is wrong is what is different between your answer and what it says in RFC 2616 as cited here, i.e. the last three words of the quoted sentence, and the manifest difference betweeen what your answer says and what the example you cited exhibits. If you can't spot that I don't think I can help you further.